# How to create arbitrary number of turtles in a loop

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I´ve tried to put them in a list:

```
import turtle
nmb = 4
turtles = [turtle.Turtle for _ in range(nmb)]
```

but when i try to move it i get

```
turtles[1].forward(10)
TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'distance'
```

When i try "setpos" i get

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_goto'
```

Maybe there are better ways to make arbitrary number of turtles. Actually i was trying to recive turtles not in the list but i didn´t find how.

Comment: This works for me... If I change the Turtle declaration to turtles = [turtle.Turtle() for _ in range(nmb)] if I don't I get a different error (unbound method forward .. on python2).   Add () to the end of the turtle.Turtle ??

Answer (score 2):

You never actually call the init for Turtle, line 3 should look like this:

```
turtles = [turtle.Turtle() for _ in range(nmb)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your turtle objects:

```
import turtle
nmb = 4
turtles = [turtle.Turtle() for _ in range(nmb)]
turtles[1].forward(10)
```

This results in your turtles advancing as expected